# How do I fix the error FIRAuth has been changed to Auth Then when I change it to Auth it says it is an unresolved identifier? What do I need to do?

Tags: swift, firebase

How would I fix the FIRAuth error and then the Auth error that appears after-words?

The code that follows is the code that I developed. The FIRAuth error is:

> FIRAuth has been changed to Auth.

Then the Auth error is an unresolved identifier.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

    var userUid: String!

    func goToCreateUserVC(){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUp", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if segue.identifier == "SignUp" {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? UserVC {
                if userUid != nil {
                    destination.userUid = userUid
                }
                if emailField.text != nil {
                    destination.emailField = emailField.text
                }
                if passwordField.text != nil {
                    destination.passwordField = passwordField.text
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func signInTapped(sender: Any){
        if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
           FIRAuth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user,error) in
                if error == nil{
                    if let user = user {
                        self.userUid = user.uid
                        self.goToCreateUserVC()
                    }
                }else{
                    self.goToCreateUserVC()
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using the latest version of Firebase I guess where FIRAuth has been renamed in Auth. You need to use Auth instead of FIRAuth.

Comment: Lack of related tags

Answer (score 1):

First, update your method: Auth.auth().signIn

Then, from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start):
Install dependency in the Podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

Initialize Firebase object in the method application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

Comment: I did this but it still gives me the same error. What should I do?

Comment: Try Clean Build Folder from the Product menu by holding Option key to select. That empties derived data folders for all targets.